# Measurable and/or integrable functions on the Cantor set $C$ or its subsets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set, borel-measures

What are some concrete examples of functions either on the ternary Cantor set $C$ or on its subsets that could be measurable and/or integrable? I've been toying with the idea of trying $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x^2$ but I'm not sure if they fit the bill. Perhaps this might first of all require us to define exactly what a measurable function and an integrable function are when restricted to the Cantor set $C$ or its subsets. How should I proceed, and are there any useful research articles on this?

Comment: Since the Cantor set has measure zero, every subset is measurable; so any function with support contained in the Cantor set is measurable.

Comment: @Arturo: What is a function with support again? I think I may have forgot that. So $x$ and $x^2$ will work here, correct?

Comment: The support of a function is the set of points in which it takes nonzero values. That is, $\mathrm{supp}(f) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cantor set is compact and therefore Borel measurable.  Take any Borel measurable function defined on $[0,1]$ and restrict it to the Cantor set. This is Borel measurable.  In fact, every Borel measurable subset of the Cantors set is some restriction of a Borel measurable function defined on [0,1]; just extend by defining it to be zero off of the Cantor set.

Notice I didn't say "Lebesgue measurable," because all subsets of the Cantor set are Lebesgue measurable.

When you say "integrable," I reply, "With respect to what measure?"  The Cantor Singular function defines a measure supported on the Cantor set. Is this the measure you are thinking of?

Comment: I was thinking in terms of Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure, something that my Real Analysis class just scratched the surface of.